# Spring Mvc jsp page gives blank output after initializing calendar using js and css files

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, spring-mvc, fullcalendar

I am not sure why I am getting a blank output from the `jsp` file when trying to initialize a calendar using the following documentation. I think I have followed the documentation on this website correctly: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/. I have attached the code on my `jsp` file and a view of the files I downloaded into the`WEB-INF` folder. Please see the image description below. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The selector for the `calendar`'s `div` is incorrect. Change it from `$('calendar')` to `$('#calendar')`.

**EDIT after comments**

Also, about deploying the static resources like  the JS, CSS, and image files: These resources must be put outside the `WEB-INF` directory. They can be put in any directory structure within your application's root directory, except in the `WEB-INF`. This is what the [Servlet 3 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says. Following is an excerpt.

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named “WEB-INF”. This
>   directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document
>   root of the application. Most of the WEB-INF node is not part of the public document
>   tree of the application. Except for static resources and JSPs packaged in the METAINF/
>   resources of a JAR file that resides in the WEB-INF/lib directory, no other
>   files contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the
>   container.

You can find out more details in "section 10.5: Directory Structure" in the spec.

So, if you do want to put your static resource within the `WEB-INF`, you would need to package them into `METAINF/resources of a JAR file that resides in the WEB-INF/lib`.

Suppose the context-path of your application (and the name of the root directory for your application in the deployment) is `context`. Now suppose you create a directory hierarchy `scripts/jquery` in that root directory, and put the `jquery.min.js` in that directory. Now, to include the `jquery.min.js` in your JSP, you can specify the following:

```
<script src="/context/scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For this to work in a spring application, you would need to put the following in your spring configuration.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

This will allow the requests for static resources to be handled by your application container itself. See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) for more details.

Comment: I had $('#calendar') previously, however it continued to give me a blank page. I tried changing it back again, still no output. Thanks though.

Comment: When the page loads, see the source of the page, are all your JS files being loaded?

Comment: By the source of the page, does it mean click on view Source after the  page is loaded on the server? I am not sure how to check whether the js files are loaded, since view source, shows me the code itself. I assumed it loads correctly, since the path given on the head of the jsp page does not give me an error.

Comment: Use chrome or firefox, press `CTRL + U` after the page loads, and in the source, try clicking on the links that represent your JS files. If they open, they are loaded correctly. Or, alternatively, use Chrome console or firebug (in firefox), go to the `sources` tab (I do not remember the name of that tab in firebug, but you can easily find out) and check out which files are loaded.

Comment: Yes that is right. Thanks! I have tried  clicking on the links and it says resources not found. Which folder are the js and full calendar file to be downloaded. I have tried downloading it WEB-INF currently; it recognizes the path, however for some reason says resources not found. I am not sure what path to use and which folder to place the files.

Comment: Put your scripts, and other resources (CSS, images), directly under your deployed application's root directory (the context-path); right besides the `WEB-INF` directory. You can use any directory structure you want, just keep them outside `WEB-INF`. If your application's context-path is 'xyz', then you can specify their paths in the JSP like `/xyz/path/to/scripts/scriptname.js`

Comment: Not sure what is wrong: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/InfantJesusChurch/WebContent/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' although I placed it in the WebContent folder, inside the full calendar folder and outside the WEB-INF folder. The same for the other two files.

Comment: Thanks greatly for the response! Appreciate the help. It was very informative!

Comment: Did it solve your problem or not? If not, what's happening now?